# no www in my var folder

Tags: directory, web-development

I started to try to install [Symfony php framework](https://symfony.com/). In the tutorial, they asked to download it and unzip the files in the usual web folder : `/var/wamp` for Linux. Yet I searched in the `var` folder and found nothing about it... Do I have to create it on my own ?  I tried using right click but I failed ...

I found [this link on how to install and get started with Symfony on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-get-started-with-symfony-2-on-ubuntu-14-04). But I rather followed George's answer to download apache2 first.

I have Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Do you have apache installed?

Comment: @George No, I don't

Comment: Default apache2 site location is `/var/www/html` not `/var/wamp`

Comment: what version of php are you using, so i can help with the `xml` requirement?

Comment: @George PHP 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, But I installed a packege and everyhing seemed to be allright. Yet, when I try to launch `http://localhost/Symfony` Apache tells me that The requested URL /Symfony was not found on this server.

Comment: was your project called `Symfony`?

Comment: @George no, myproject. I changed and understood the error. Thank you for your help so far. My last question would be why, when I launch `http://localhost:8000/` do I have An error while loading the web debug toolbar `(500: Internal Server Error)` ? Should I open PHPStorm ?

Comment: PhpStorm prefers to use its own server so the error are you launching the app from PhpStorm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please install `apache`:

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

Then go to `/var/` you should see `www` and inside it `html` since Ubuntu 14.04, so drop it in `/var/www/html` as this is the default for `Ubuntu 14.04 +`

Comment: Thank you ! Should I move the Symfony file which is in `usr/olcal/bin` for the moment ?

Comment: No leave it there that is where it should be, just use it any where like `/var/www/html/` to create a new project in the `html` directory!

Comment: To create a project in `/var/www/html/` do `cd /var/www/html` then `sudo symfony new myproject` in there and you will now have `/var/www/html/myproject`!

Comment: Shouldn't I install a whole LAMP server ? With the following command line : `sudo apt install apache2 php mysql-server libapache2-mod-php php-mysql`

Comment: Sure but remember that `apache` is already installed so remove it from the `install command`!

Comment: What should I do if it is to late (I thought it would just erase and give a new copy)?

Comment: Yes you can do that remove it then run `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` it will install all that is needed!

Comment: So I just do `rm apache2 php mysql-server libapache2-mod-php php-mysql` and then `sudo apt-get install lamp-server`?

Comment: Please don't if all are already install its counter intuitive to do that just leave them as they are it will still work as expected, but if you want to install on new system then use that shorten command!